# Scala RegexParsers

Tags: scala

I am using the following object to parse csv.  The parser seems to be working correctly except  spaces are being stripped out.  Could someone help me figure out where that is happening.  Thanks

```
object CsvParser extends RegexParsers {
  override protected val whiteSpace = """[ \t]""".r

  def COMMA = ","
  def DQUOTE = "\""
  def DQUOTE2 = "\"\"" ^^ { case _ => "\"" }
  def CR = "\r"
  def LF = "\n"
  def CRLF = "\r\n"
  def TXT = "[^\",\r\n]".r

  def record: Parser[List[String]] = rep1sep(field, COMMA)
  def field: Parser[String] = (escaped | nonescaped)
  def escaped: Parser[String] = (DQUOTE ~> ((TXT | COMMA | CR | LF | DQUOTE2)*) <~ DQUOTE) ^^ { case ls => ls.mkString("") }
  def nonescaped: Parser[String] = (TXT*) ^^ { case ls => ls.mkString("") }

  def parse(s: String) = parseAll(record, s) match {
    case Success(res, _) => res
    case _ => List[List[String]]()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  Needed to add:

```
override val skipWhitespace = false
```